# In what set is this brick used?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

[image: photo]

In which set is this LEGO brick used? There is no number in it and it's original LEGO. The only number on it is "A 1".

Answer (score 14):

The specific part (870) is identified in the other answer, however it is part of an assembly with its own part number:

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=827#T=C&C=3

827 Vehicle, Tractor Chassis

870's page mentions it has extra parts that it is used with, and 827 is the complete assembly (steering wheel + mechanism).

This page details what other parts are needed to complete it.

https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?P=827

870 is the base in the picture, and 871-874 are the mechanism pieces.

Comment: The first link in your question is identical to the one in Henrik's answer.

Comment: How do I edit this the best way? I see the redundancy but the point here is to give the extra information. Do I just remove the link?..

Comment: Maybe post the extra info as a comment to his answer, why not?

Comment: I've seen people post add-on answers elsewhere so I figured it would be fine here - especially since when I started searching there was no answer yet

Comment: Okay, but in that case just edit your answer to explain that you're posting this to add some context and don't say "this is the **real** part" because we already know what the real part is.

Comment: Oh, with that I meant that while this is the specific part, it is useful to know that it is not a standalone piece. Not good with words, will try to reword it.

Comment: I disagree with mindstormsboi here, your answer is just as valid as the other one. Also your answer in original form was fine.

Answer (score 12):

That's
[Vehicle, Tractor Chassis Base 11 x 2 x 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=870&name=Vehicle,%20Tractor%20Chassis%20Base%2011%20x%202%20x%203&category=%5BVehicle%5D#T=C&C=3)

Following the link to bricklink, you can see that it was in four sets in the 1970's.